# What is the point of configuring an output as "push-pull" and "pull-down" at the same time?

Tags: stm32, gpio, pullup, pulldown, push-pull

In CubeMX, there is still "pull-up" and "pull-down" options listed for an output while that output is already configured as "push-pull". How does it make sense to configure an output as both "Pull-up/down" and "Push-pull" at the same time?

[image]

How could a pull-up or pull-down resistor make any electrical difference (benefits) on a push-pull output?

Comment: The Pull-up/pull-down choice may only be effective if the pin is configured as an output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pull-up or pull-down would make sense if the IO pin is configured to be an input, or at least a pull-up would make sense if it is configured to be an open-drain output.

Not all combinations that are possible to select in hardware and software are useful. It really does not make sense to be a push-pull output with pull-down resistor enabled.

But, for example, it might make sense to have a pull-up or pull-down, if the IO pin is for example used as a bi-directional data bus for a memory chip, or SDIO card, or something along that line.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the push/pull refers to the output driver, and the pull-down refers to a resistor which could be attached to an input or an output.

One possibility is that the pin is part of a tri-state bus (and/or bidirectional signal line), and you want to introduce a default value so it doesn't float when all outputs on the bus are in hi-Z state.

Comment: But this setting is individual for each pin. The same pin is configured with push-pull output and pull-down.

Comment: Right.  It makes sense if you remember the output and pullup/down are separate circuit elements that can be applied internally to the pin.